# Why does the arima function sometimes produce strange parameter estimates?

Tags: arima, estimation

The arima function in base R produces strange (if not wrong) results in certain situations. These results seem to contradict the well-known theoretical properties of ARIMA models (e.g., when MA parameters are near the invertibility boundaries or when time series are relatively short).

If you run the following R script in the console, you will see the value of the seasonal MA parameter for increasing time series lengths.

```
Z = log(AirPassengers)
result = NULL
for(i in 40:144) {
  result = rbind(result, c(i, arima(Z[1:i], order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12))$coef[[2]]))
}
plot(result, type = "l", xlab = "ts length", ylab = "seasonal Theta1")
```

The plot shows that the parameter value is -1 for lengths ranging from roughly 40 - 60 observations. This value corresponds (in the right hand side of the equation) with (1 - B^s) which means that it cancels out the seasonal differencing operator (basically, the arima function tells us that seasonal differencing is not necessary which is very strange). I have also compared the estimates with other algorithms and they do not behave like this (the seasonal Theta parameters are slowly changing as the time series length varies). The predictions of those models look reasonable and contain seasonality though... how is that possible? Can we trust the arima parameters?